# prevent syno abb from complaining about failed backups

Tags: synology-diskstation

I have migrated a laptop from windows to linux, and therefore no longer use Synology's Active Backup for Business (ABB) for that laptop (I use it for others). However, despite changing the backup schedule to "Manual", the syno interface still alarms periodically to say that the backup was unsuccessful:

[image: ABB task scheduler]

I need to keep the backups themselves according to the `Retention` schedule, which should always keep at least the 10 most recent:

[image: ABB retention rules]

Is there a way to prevent the periodic "backup task was unsuccessful" message/warning without endangering keeping the backups? I feel that if I were to delete the device, it would get rid of all of the backups as well.

DSM 7.2.1-69057 Update 4 on a DS918+.